# Achieving min-content and percentage width in css grid?

Tags: css

I have some elements that display a key/value list. I'm using css grid to ensure the "key" span "column" is the same width, so the list looks nice. `min-content` is a good way do this.

However, if the width of the parent DIV is too small to display everything, I need the key column to shrink to give more space to the "value" column. Something like `grid-column-template: 1fr 2fr` can do this acceptably.

The problem is that I can't use both settings at the same time. `min-content` doesn't do what I need when the panel is small, and nothing else seems to do what I need when large.

To clarify, I need to do the following:

- At all times, the "key" spans must be the same length. Usually the length of the longest "cell".
- When the div is wide, the "key" span must be `min-content`: as wide as the longest "cell".
- When the div is narrower, the "key" span must collapse so that the "value" doesn't overflow.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/helion3/pen/poZKvGm)

```css
.panel {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.text-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel thin">
  <span class="text-ellipsis">key:</span>
  <span class="text-ellipsis">value</span>
  <span class="text-ellipsis">some really long key that should be truncated:</span>
  <span class="text-ellipsis">some really long value that should be truncated</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`minmax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) css function to restrict the length of each column:

```css
grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, min-content) minmax(max-content, 1fr);
```

```css
.panel {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, min-content) minmax(max-content, 1fr);
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel thin">
  <span class="text-ellipsis">key:</span>
  <span class="text-ellipsis">value</span>
  <span class="text-ellipsis">some really long key that should be truncated:</span>
  <span class="text-ellipsis">some really long value that should be truncated</span>
</div>

<h3 style="text-align: right;">Resize it by dragging this ↑</h3>
```

Comment: That's definitely closer! I notice that if it's too small the value vanishes entirely, I'll have play around with the settings to have some absolute minimum

Comment: @helion3 Yes, I changed to min value of the key to `50px`, so now at lease you can see some of the key column. You can set the minimum value arbitrarily.

Comment: Playing with this more I think it's not going to work because the value text gets cut off, the text-ellipsis no longer applies because the width might be too long and overflow the panel.  What I wish I could do is say min-content is the default but 50% of the container is the max for both - but that will just do exactly what I don't want when the container is very wide.

Comment: You're right, because the min value is set to `max-content` so it won't go below that. I'm also looking for a solution right now so excuse me for a few minute 

Comment: Right now the best solution for my use is something like `minmax(50px, min-content) minmax(100px, 1fr);` but if the parent container drops below those pixel values, the text-overflow is cut off. I can live with that at such small sizes if there's no better solution

Comment: Actually `minmax(50px, min-content) minmax(60%, max-content);` is a little better too - gives priority to the value column without losing text-overflow until the min pixel sizes are hit

Comment: Yes, but it's still a workaround. The main problem is there's no property like `flex-shrink` to determine which columns should be shinked prioritized in grid layout(or maybe I don't know of).

Comment: Agreed, but honestly this is close enough it's acceptable - far better than where I started. Thanks!